# How to retrieve remote IP address in an Axios call from Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I would like to get the resolved IP address of the remote url when I make an axios call in Node. See *** comment below. Thanks a lot in advance!

```js
axios.get('http://www.example.com')
  .then(function (response) {
    // *** How can I get the resolved IP address of www.example.com here
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Do you have access to the remote server (as in do you manage it)? you can only do this if you have access to the remote url server. you only have access to HTTP headers and unless the remote server specifically provides its ip address as part of the headers, you wont be able to access it.

Answer (score 3):

The Axios documentation states `response.request` "is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)."

```js
axios.get('http://www.example.com')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.request.socket.remoteAddress);
  });
```

Comment: In answer you have mentioned  `request.response` but in code, you have written `response.request`, which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Axios will return you the response headers and the body of your request, ussualy you can't get the ip address from headers if there is not specified one, but you can use [`dns`](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html) module from node.js`.

```
const dns = require('dns');

dns.resolve4('archive.org', (err, addresses) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`addresses: ${JSON.stringify(addresses)}`);
});
```

Comment: Wouldnt the DNS call waste some time to resolve the IP. I was hoping the IP is already resolved in the axios call and I can grab it from there.. I would like to avoid an extra dns call if possible.

Comment: Actually you can run in parallel the 2 calls, and then you will not waste any time...

Comment: Yes then you have to sync the two calls because I need the response and IP address at the same time for logging. Your solution will work but it may complicate the code a bit. Before I do that, I am hoping someone can confirm if axios has it buried somewhere in the response that I can use.